# Adding Columns with Text Boxes to an Existing Access Report without messing up the format

Tags: ms-access, report

Ok, I know this is dumb, dumb question, forgive me, I can't for the life of me figure it out.

So I used the Report Wizard to create a report with a few fields. So far, so good. I got columns and they're grouped with column labels, a little blue line under each label and I can drag the columns around to reorder them.

I'd like to add a few text fields with labels to that group of columns. I could just add them outside the column grouping that the Report Wizard gave me but then it never looks right (and I can't reorder the fields with a simple click n drag).

This seems like something I should be able to do easily but I can't find the option. I know it's possible because I've seen it done in other DBs. Anyone know what I'm missing/misunderstanding?

Comment: I seldom use any of the design wizards because they do things I don't like and I have never even looked at the Report Wizard - until now. Cannot replicate the issue. I do not see 'little blue line'. How do you get the 'columns'?

Comment: To my knowledge, the wizard doesn't do anything that can't be added or edited in other ways.  Unless you explain otherwise, I assume the controls (a.k.a. fields) are in a groups that you can add or manipulate with the options on the Arrange ribbon (i.e. toolbar).  It is strange that it won't let you drag and drop, but there are are "Move Up" and "Move Down" buttons on the Arrange Ribbon.  Do those buttons or other Arrange options work for you?

Comment: Sorry, the 'blue line' is just formatting. I should have left it out of my explanation since it's not really relevant :).   

When you add fields to a report using the wizard it groups them into some kind of a container with each field in labeled columns. In design view if I click one of the labels/fields I'll see a handle icon that can be clicked to select everything in the container.    

OTOH if I just select a single column in the container I can click and drag to change the column order. What I can't figure out is what that container is called and how I add columns to it.

Comment: Or Lord, I think I just figured it out.

I can drag and drop fields from the "Add Existing Fields" container and then edit the text inside the field to be the formula I want it to be (e.g. "=[My_Field_Name] + 90" if I want to add 90 to the field "My_Field_Name"). What I can't do is add a text box to the grouping. 

I'm pretty sure this is the worst possible way to do what I'm doing, but I'm not the one who made the DB, I'm just trying to add to it. When I get some time I'll re-do the whole thing from scratch with proper data structures.